# In MFC CArray, what are reasons to use different default template type?

Tags: c++, templates, mfc

The MFC CArray class has two template parameters (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

```
template < class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE = const TYPE& > 
class CArray
...
```

The default parameter for `ARG_TYPE` is `const TYPE&`, and some questions on SO ask when to use a type different from the default (e.g. [Should the ARG_TYPE for a CArray be const & or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147944/should-the-arg-type-for-a-carray-be-const-or-not), or [What's the difference between CArray and CArray ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693147/whats-the-difference-between-carrayint-int-and-carrayint-int)).

My questions are now: Are there reasonable use cases of CArray where the ARG_TYPE isn't `TYPE` or `const TYPE&`, e.g. another class? What are the reasons for these usages?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but **DO NOT** use `CArray`. It is a horrible class that will copy its elements using `memcpy` instead of copy construction. So if you use it to hold an array of objects that contain pointers your application will crash. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I'm searching for arguments not to use CArray and to convince colleagues to use std::vector, and I wondered about this oddity. CMap is even more horrible with 4 template parameters and a complicated way to determine sort order in the map...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, it should be related to inheritance hierarchy.

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

CArray<D, const B&> myArray;
```

You may want to have the base `class` as the receiving argument, which can receive a `const` reference from the derived `class`.

Answer (score 1):

My best example is `CArray <CString, LPCTSTR>`. In fact, I recall `CArray <CString, CString&>` didn't work very well...